# Got an error: Property 'gridOptions' does not exist on type 'HTMLInputElement'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have these codes

table.component.ts:

```
export class TableComponent {
  private gridOptions:GridOptions;

  constructor() {
    this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{};
    this.gridOptions.headerCellRenderer = this.headerCellRendererFunc;
  }

  private headerCellRendererFunc(e){
    console.log(e.value);
    if (e.value !== 'checkbox') {
      return e.value;
    }

    var cb = document.createElement('input');
    cb.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
    var eHeader = document.createElement('label');
    eHeader.appendChild(cb);
    cb.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
      if (e[0].checked) {
        this.gridOptions.api.selectAll();
      } else {
        this.gridOptions.api.deselectAll();
      }
    });

    return eHeader;
  }  
}
```

The error is on:

```
cb.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if (e[0].checked) {
    this.gridOptions.api.selectAll();
  } else {
    this.gridOptions.api.deselectAll();
  }
});
```

It does not recognize this.gridOptions.
it seems "this" scope is on the addEventListener.

How do I refer to gridOptions of class TableComponent?

Answer (score 0):

Use an arrow function to maintain the surrounding `this`:

```
cb.addEventListener('change', e => {
  if (e[0].checked) {
    this.gridOptions.api.selectAll();
  } else {
    this.gridOptions.api.deselectAll();
  }
});
```

Comment: I used your solution. though there is no more compile error but in run-time. I got this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'gridOptions' of undefined. It seems "this" became undefined.